# Chicken or the egg?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am not quite sure how to approach this and appreciate everyone's input.

I need to make a vnet and provision a windows server.  No big deal so far.  But after the windows server is provisioned, I will be elevating it to a domain controller.

I then need to go back to the vnet and set DNS to the IP of the windows server that I provisioned *after* the vnet.

How do I set the DNS server for the vnet if the server isn't setup yet?  I can't setup the server w/out the vnet up first.

How do you approach this?

thank you much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into this in the future, the answer is assign a static IP to the server so you can assign that same IP to the DNS in the vnet.  doh!